# Make fulfilled hierarchy from data with levels

Tags: python, pandas, hierarchy, reshape

I have a table which looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd

x = '1233312332344344'
y = ['Name_' + str(i) for i, _ in enumerate(x)]

df = pd.DataFrame({'level': list(x), 'names': y})
```

Looks like this:

```
   level    names
0      1   Name_0
1      2   Name_1
2      3   Name_2
3      3   Name_3
4      3   Name_4
5      1   Name_5
6      2   Name_6
7      3   Name_7
8      3   Name_8
9      2   Name_9
10     3  Name_10
11     4  Name_11
12     4  Name_12
13     3  Name_13
14     4  Name_14
15     4  Name_15
```

Is there a way to reshape this df with pandas, to get this result (based on level column)?

```
  1       2        3      4
Name_0          
Name_0  Name_1      
Name_0  Name_1  Name_2  
Name_0  Name_1  Name_3  
Name_0  Name_1  Name_4  
Name_5          
Name_5  Name_6      
Name_5  Name_6  Name_7  
Name_5  Name_6  Name_8  
Name_5  Name_9      
Name_5  Name_9  Name_10 
Name_5  Name_9  Name_10 Name_11
Name_5  Name_9  Name_10 Name_12
Name_5  Name_9  Name_13 
Name_5  Name_9  Name_13 Name_14
Name_5  Name_9  Name_13 Name_15
```

This is a kind of source df but with all hierarchy levels filled in the rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dummies = pd.get_dummies(df.level)
d = dummies.mask(dummies == 0).bfill(1).eq(1)
df.set_index('level', append=True).names.unstack().ffill().where(d, '')

level       1       2        3        4
0      Name_0                          
1      Name_0  Name_1                  
2      Name_0  Name_1   Name_2         
3      Name_0  Name_1   Name_3         
4      Name_0  Name_1   Name_4         
5      Name_5                          
6      Name_5  Name_6                  
7      Name_5  Name_6   Name_7         
8      Name_5  Name_6   Name_8         
9      Name_5  Name_9                  
10     Name_5  Name_9  Name_10         
11     Name_5  Name_9  Name_10  Name_11
12     Name_5  Name_9  Name_10  Name_12
13     Name_5  Name_9  Name_13         
14     Name_5  Name_9  Name_13  Name_14
15     Name_5  Name_9  Name_13  Name_15
```

Comment: I didn't quite got the logic of empty rows.

Comment: my `set_index` and `unstack` is identical to your pivot.  But OP wanted rows filled out only so far as where the level got to.  So, for row 9, level is 2, so only fill row up to column of level 2.

Comment: Ah. Thanks. Got it.

Comment: Thank you so much! Very interesting solution.